# jsp form validation with balloon popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created below form and want to validate each textbox after clicking on Sign Up button.

I am new to javascript and don't know how it works. Also need to display error message near textbox as balloon popup.

Kindly suggest javascript useful tips.

[image: Form to be validated]

Below javascript is submitting value in database even after I fill in any one of the below mentioned textbox. But actual case should be like it scans each and every textbox sequentially and display error message.

```
function validateform()
{  

    var fn=document.getElementsByName("fname")[0].value;

    if(fn==null || fn==""){
        document.getElementById("bubble1").style.visibility="visible";
        return false;
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("bubble1").style.visibility="hidden";
        return true;
    }

    var ln=document.getElementsByName("lname")[0].value;

    if(ln==null || ln==""){
        document.getElementById("bubble2").style.visibility="visible";
        return false;
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("bubble2").style.visibility="hidden";
        return true;
    }
}
```

Kindly suggest what went wrong!

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of doing what you achieved, most of them are done with js event handlers.
You could use different event "types" in this case, depending on when you want to display the errors, I would suggest using **on submit** on the form button in your case, but you could also check **on change** for every input, in order to immediately display an error to the user.

The simplest way, using pure javascript, could be something like that:

```
   <form action="youraction" method="post" onsubmit="checkFields();">
   ....
   </form>
```

In your js code you will need something like this:

```
   function checkFields(){
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var surname = document.getElementById("surname ").value;
    ...

    //validate your text fields, using regular expressions maybe
    if (!checkMail(email)){
      //attach a div to the body(absolute positioning) with the error
      return false; //this is important, it prevents the window from refreshing, aborting the submit
     }
     .....
     return true //everything is good, you can submit
  }
```

There are tons of other ways, using jQuery for example, but this might work just fine.

Comment: Hi Pix, Great explanation. Could you please help me out on same and let me know if we can perform the validation after `onblur()`.

Comment: Absolutely, as I said, there are many other ways ^^ Using onblur on every input, you can directly call the function that validates your input field as soon as you leave the field, that's a good idea. You will still need the onsubmit control, because you only want to submit when every field is ready. So better to leave an extra check when submitting!